# T901 Fujitsu Touch Screen Disable Hand Touch

Tags: screen

I have a T901 Fujitsu with a touch screen and I want to disable the hand input, but leave the input from the pen so I can easily write on my screen without my hand interfering. Does anyone know of a simple(ish) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're still interested in the answer: yes, there is a very easy way to do this. The trick is `xsetwacom`, the programme that takes care of most touch screen related stuff.

If you enter `xsetwacom --list devices` in a terminal, a list should show up with the different touch screen devices on your computer. For me it shows:

```
tomas@EliteBook:~$ xsetwacom --list devices
Serial Wacom Tablet stylus          id: 16  type: STYLUS    
Serial Wacom Tablet eraser          id: 18  type: ERASER    
Serial Wacom Tablet touch           id: 19  type: TOUCH
```

All you should need to do is turn the `Touch` parameter `off` for one of these devices (it worked for me whether I did it for the stylus or the touch). In my case I enter:

```
xsetwacom --set 19 touch off
```

You might want to replace the number with whatever shows up on your computer, or better yet, the name of the device in "quotes", as the number might change when other devices have been connected to your computer . If you turn that into a script, you could even bind it to a shortkey through e.g. CCSM.

Hope the information is still useful for you, please let me know if it is and explain why not if it isn't.